# How to extract particular values from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which looks like this:

```
[{'Score': 0.9979117512702942, 'Type': 's_merchant', 'Text': 'merchants', 'BeginOffset': 7, 'EndOffset': 16}, {'Score': 0.9997400045394897, 'Type': 'metric', 'Text': 'number of errors', 'BeginOffset': 22, 'EndOffset': 38}, {'Score': 0.9984105825424194, 'Type': 'metric', 'Text': 'order rate', 'BeginOffset': 43, 'EndOffset': 53}, {'Score': 0.997801661491394, 'Type': 'user_service', 'Text': 'search requests', 'BeginOffset': 57, 'EndOffset': 72}, {'Score': 0.999964714050293, 'Type': 'PROPERTY', 'Text': 'revenue', 'BeginOffset': 20, 'EndOffset': 27}, {'Score': 0.999964714050293, 'Type': 'PROPERTY_VAL', 'Text': 'gold', 'BeginOffset': 28, 'EndOffset': 32}, {'Score': 0.9646918177604675, 'Type': 'ORGANIZATION', 'Text': 'Gymshark', 'BeginOffset': 22, 'EndOffset': 30}]
```

I need to extract all the values from keys 'Type' (which is basically 's_merchant' for the first dictionary) and 'Text'( which is 'merchants' for the first dictionary) from all the dictionaries in the list.

The output should be a list, something like this:

```
Type=['s_merchant','metric','user_service','PROPERTY','PROPERTY_VAL','ORGANIZATION'] 
Text=['merchants','number of errors','order rate','revenue','gold','Gymshark']
```

Is there a function/method to accomplish this?
Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [python's list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which allows more compact synthax than regular loop:

```py
l = [{'Score': 0.9979117512702942, 'Type': 's_merchant', 'Text': 'merchants', 'BeginOffset': 7, 'EndOffset': 16}, {'Score': 0.9997400045394897, 'Type': 'metric', 'Text': 'number of errors', 'BeginOffset': 22, 'EndOffset': 38}, {'Score': 0.9984105825424194, 'Type': 'metric', 'Text': 'order rate', 'BeginOffset': 43, 'EndOffset': 53}, {'Score': 0.997801661491394, 'Type': 'user_service', 'Text': 'search requests', 'BeginOffset': 57, 'EndOffset': 72}, {'Score': 0.999964714050293, 'Type': 'PROPERTY', 'Text': 'revenue', 'BeginOffset': 20, 'EndOffset': 27}, {'Score': 0.999964714050293, 'Type': 'PROPERTY_VAL', 'Text': 'gold', 'BeginOffset': 28, 'EndOffset': 32}, {'Score': 0.9646918177604675, 'Type': 'ORGANIZATION', 'Text': 'Gymshark', 'BeginOffset': 22, 'EndOffset': 30}]


Type = [i['Type'] for i in l]
Text = [i['Text'] for i in l]
```

To remove duplicate values in list, a good option is to use a **set** object like:

```py
list(set(Type))
```

With your example, just do:

```py
Type = list(set([i['Type'] for i in l]))
```

Comment: the value 'metric' comes twice, is there a way get unique values?

Comment: See my update, just do ```Type = list(set([i['Type'] for i in l]))```

Answer (score 1):

```
Type = []
Text = []
for s in list_dicts :
  Type.append(s['Type'])
  Text.append(s['Text'])
```

Or with less code by using comprehension lists (but it's quite the same thing) :

```
Type = [s['Type'] for s in list_dicts]
Text = [s['Text'] for s in list_dicts]
```